# How to change style in specific row in Element UI Table

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm using Element UI for my web app.
In my app, there is a table component, that is made by `el-table` component provided by Element UI.

And I would like to change style for the only specific row.

Firstly, please take a look at the screenshot and my code, later, I will explain what I would like to do specifically with them.

These are the screenshot of table in my app and my code.

[image]

```
<template>
  <el-table
    :data="tableData"
    height="250"
    style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column
      prop="date"
      label="Date"
      width="180">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
      prop="name"
      label="Name"
      width="180">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
      prop="address"
      label="Address">
    </el-table-column>
  </el-table>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        tableData: [{
          date: '2016-05-03',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-02',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-04',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-01',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-08',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-06',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-07',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }],
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I would like to change background color blue for the row that's Data is `2016-05-03` and `2016-05-04` in the case above.

Comment: You can create/edit custom style for Element-UI, 
https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/theme/preview

Comment: @Momin Thanks, how to apply custom style for a specific row? And I assume tableData is dynamic data coming from the backend API. So I need to apply custom style dynamically after fetching the tableData from backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at this https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table-with-status. based on the property `row-class-name` you can apply some logic to add an class to the row.

```
<el-table
    :data="tableData"
    style="width: 100%"
    :row-class-name="tableRowClassName">
```

JS

```
methods: {
  tableRowClassName({row, rowIndex}) {
    if (row.date >= new Date()) {
      return 'warning-row';
    } else if (rowIndex === 3) {
      return 'success-row';
    }
    return '';
  }
},
```

Of course you've to customize this to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on the component stylesheet

```
.el-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #845353;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is only for the odd rows.

Comment: Interesting! I was work on the Element UI custom style, but data dependent style for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally +

If you are using the new version of Element-UI and **row-style** instead of **header-row-class-name**, you must not use like `return: 'background: red'`. You have to return **Object**.

ex: `return: {'background': 'red'}`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30748285)